# Controller method from unit test in the same solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, httpclient

How I can call method from controller in the same solution. HttpClient or something else ?

I can’t use full url address like “https://path…”.I need to call it from controller

My method looks like:

```
[HttpPost(nameof(AcceptBidDeliveryDateOutOfSchedule))]
public Task<AcceptBidDeliveryDateOutOfScheduleBySupplierCommandResponse>
  AcceptBidDeliveryDateOutOfSchedule(
    AcceptBidDeliveryDateOutOfScheduleBySupplierCommand command,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    _currentUserContext.UserLogin = nameof(AcceptBidDeliveryDateOutOfSchedule);

    return _mediator.SendExternal<
      AcceptBidDeliveryDateOutOfScheduleBySupplierCommand,
      AcceptBidDeliveryDateOutOfScheduleBySupplierCommandResponse>
        (command, cancellationToken);
}
```

I tried to use PostAsync, but I don't know how I can call with custom parameters

Comment: If you're invoking a controller method in a *unit test* then generally you would just create an instance of the controller and call the method directly.

Comment: Could also use a WebApplicationFactory so that your actual program class is instantiated along with all of its dependencies.

Comment: If this isn’t a unit test then I’d probably extract the logic of the other controller into another function personally